# Select String From Text File and Create variable

Tags: powershell

I have a text file containing a string I need to make a variable.  I need the value for "file" to be retained as a variable.  How can I capture this and make it a variable: "\APPSRV\I\Run\OPTI\CLIENT\20171031\25490175\Data\brtctybv\".  This data will change per file, but it will retain the same format, it will start with \ and end with \

Example Text File

```
order_id = 25490175-brtctybv
file     = \\APPSRV\I\Run\OPTI\CLIENT\20171031\25490175\Data\brtctybv\
copies   = 1
volume   = 20171031-brtctybv
label    = \\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\OPTI\CLIENT\Cdlab\somefile.file
merge    = \\APPSRV\I\Run\OPTI\CLIENT\20171031\25490175\mrg\25490175-brtctybv.MRG
FIXATE   = NOAPPEND
```

Comment: Do you mean "retained as the value of a variable"?

Comment: Yes, I need the selected string to be retained as the value of a variable.  I'm having having a hard time trying to figure out how to grab that UNC path out of the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = ((Get-Content -path file.txt) | Select-String -pattern "^file\s*=\s*(\\\\.*\\)").matches.groups[1].value
$file
```

See [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a599gm/1) to see the regex in action. The `.matches.groups[1].value` is grabbing the value of capture group 1. The capture group is created by the `()` within the pattern. See [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) for more information about the cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks AoT, regex god

Comment: Thanks for the RegEx Demo update, very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are powerful, but complex; sometimes there are conceptually simpler alternatives:

```
PS> ((Get-Content -Raw file.txt).Replace('\', '\\') | ConvertFrom-StringData).file

\\APPSRV\I\Run\OPTI\CLIENT\20171031\25490175\Data\brtctybv\
```

- The [`ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) is built for parsing key-value pairs separated by `=`
- `\` in the values is interpreted as an *escape character*, however, hence the *doubling* of `\` in the input file with `.Replace('\', '\\')`.
- The result is a hash table (type `[hashtable]`); `Get-Content -Raw` - the input file read as a *single string* - is used to ensure that a *single* hash table is output); accessing its `file` key retrieves the associated value.